# Cannot install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, 16.04, windows-10, xps

I have to install Ubuntu alongside windows 10 (UEFI boot) on a brand new Dell XPS 13.

I already have:

- Shrinked the Windows 10 disk to have 200Gb unused space
- Disabled Secure boot
- Created the USB boot loader, and boot with it

The problem, is that, when the installer starts, it doesn't see the laptop disk, so I cannot go on with the install

Comment: Nope, it's not a duplicate. It's a different issue, since Secure Boot is disabled the installer starts correctly from USB, but the installer simply do not see the laptop disk (so no unused space on the disk, nor windows partitions)

Comment: UPDATE: Setting "Legacy Boot" isteadn of UEFI make the installer see the disk

Comment: Can you please boot the "Try Ubuntu" option from the installation medium and include the output of `sudo gdisk -l`?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have not formatted the 200GB of unused space yet?

Usually, when installing a second OS on a drive, the installer for the second OS will need the space to be formatted.

If this is the case and you are able to boot into and use your Windows 10 OS, I would suggest using the tool MiniTool partition Wizard. I believe you can google and find a download pretty easily. If you open the program and click to use the trial version, you should be able to view the 200GB of free space and format it using the tools default formatting settings. Ubuntu should then be able to view it and work with it from there when you boot using a usb.

NOTE: Be careful and make sure that this is your issue before performing operations with the partition tool, and be careful not to manipulate drives or files that you do not want to, though as changes can be permanent and file loss can result!!!

Comment: I'm not sure that will fix the problem, since I don't see the WHOLE disk, not only the "unused space".  I don't see the windows partitions either, just the SD from which I've done the boot

Comment: Fromatter the partition to FATex (the only option along with NTFS). Same behaviour.